# Problem with bundle value

Tags: android

I have 3 activities A,B and C. Activity A contains a list of items. When we click a row in Activity A, it calls Activity B which describes the item. In activity B i have another list. When I click on a row in it, it calls Activity C.

I have to pass `id` field from A to B and then to C.

Suppose I have values

```
Small
Medium
```

in Activity A.

I am clicking `Small` from this and going to Activity B and then to C. Everything works fine. The `id` passed is also correct throughout the activities.

Now from C, I am clicking phone's back button and going to B and then agin clicking phone's back button and going to A.

Now I am clicking `Medium` from the list. The `id` is correctly passed to B. But when I reach C, its not going to `onCreate()` instead to `onResume()`. There I am getting `id` value as the old one, of that of `Small`. But I want the correct id. What may be the reason for this issue? Could anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think.. U have to finish the `activity` when u r handling the `back` button in Activity C

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
           finish();
    }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: by giving this, my complete application is getting closed. My complete activities are inside an activity group

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because Activity C doesn't get killed, only suspended.

I haven't tested, but I'm fairly certain that if you pass the data via [Intent.putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20long%5B%5D%29), you should get the behaviour you're looking for (I sincerely hope different extra-data causes a new instance to get launched)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge in android activity get destroyed when you press back button(by default).
I suspect you might be dong something wrong while passing data between activities. 
But still if you fill it is related to activity is not getting destroyed. You can finish your Activity C in onPause() method. It will resolve your problem.